# IE6 Issue with CSS Menu hover

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

This basic menu works perfectly in all modern browsers but is not playing ball in IE6.

Here is the [JSDOit example](http://jsdo.it/mcgarriers/6Jdl).

And my HTML/CSS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

  <head>

    <title>CSS Test</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
        * {margin:0;padding:0}

        /* Mega Menu */
        #mega {
            list-style:none;
        }

        #mega li {
            float:left;
            position:relative;
        }

        #mega li:hover {
            border-bottom:0;
            margin-top:-7px;
            z-index:1;
            padding:7px 0 1px;
            cursor:pointer
        }

        #mega a:hover{
            cursor:pointer
        }

        #mega a {
            color:#000;
            outline:0;
            text-decoration:none;
            display:block;
            line-height:2em;
        }

        #mega div {
            position:absolute;
            left:-999em;
            margin-top:58px;
            margin-left:1px;
            width:350px;
            border-top:0;
            font-weight:400;
            text-align:left;
            background:#00B8F1;
            padding:0 10px 10px;
        }

        #mega li:hover div {
            left:-1px;
            top:auto;
        }

        #mega li.dif:hover div {
            left:-221px;
        }

        #mega div p {
            float:left;
            width:106px;
            padding-left:10px;
            position:relative;
        }

        #mega div p a {
            text-decoration:underline;
            float:left;
            clear:left;
            width:100%;
            line-height:1.4;
        }

        #mega div a:hover,#mega div a:focus,#mega div a:active {
            text-decoration:none;
        }

        #mega div .s1,#mega div .s2,#mega div .s3 {
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }

        #mega div .s1 {
            background:url(images/rightcorner.png) 100% 0 no-repeat;
            top:1px;
            right:-9px;
        }

        #mega div .s2 {
            background:url(images/leftcorner.png) 0 100% no-repeat;
            bottom:-9px;
            left:1px;
        }

        #mega div .s3 {
            background:url(images/shadow.png) 100% 100%;
            top:9px;
            right:-9px;
        }

        #mega li:hover .s4 {
            background:url(images/li-shadow.png) 100% 0 repeat-y;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            right:-9px;
            height:100%;
            padding:0 8px 0 0;
        }

        * html #mega li:hover .s4 {
            background:none;
        }

        #mega li:hover .dif-s4 {
            padding-bottom:9px;
        }

        ul#mega li .sub {
            top:58px;
            left:0;
            position:absolute;
            float:left;
            width:440px!important;
            display:none;
            padding:20px;
        }

        li#di div {
            background-position:100px 0;
        }

        #mega li a#delivery-info {
            width:102px;
            height:59px;
            position:relative;
        }

        #mega li a#delivery-info span {
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }

        #mega li:hover a#delivery-info span {
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }

        ul#topnav,ul#mega {
            float:left;
            width:100%;
            list-style:none;
            font-size:1.1em;
        }

        ul#topnav li,ul#mega li {
            float:left;
            position:relative;
            z-index:1;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        ul#topnav li a,ul#mega li a {
            float:left;
            line-height:1.6em;
        }

        ul#topnav li:hover a,ul#topnav li a:hover,ul#mega li:hover a,ul#mega li a:hover {
            background-position:left bottom;
        }

        ul#topnav li .row,ul#mega li .row {
            clear:both;
            float:left;
            width:100%;
            margin-bottom:10px;
        }

        ul#topnav li .sub ul,ul#mega li .sub ul {
            list-style:none;
            width:150px;
            float:left;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        ul#topnav .sub ul li,ul#mega .sub ul li {
            width:100%;
            color:#fff;
        }
    </style>


  </head>  

    <body>

    <div id="bar" style="height:60px">&nbsp;</div>

        <div id="container"> 

             <div id="middle">

                <div id="nav"> 

                    <ul id="mega">
                      <li id="di"><a href="/" id="delivery-info" class="delivery-info" title="Delivery Info"><span></span>Delivery Info</a>  
                      <b class="s4"></b> 
                          <div> <b class="s1"></b><b class="s2"></b><b class="s3"></b><br /><br />
                            <p><a href="#">Lots of links go here</a></p> 
                            <p><a href="#">Lots of links go here</a></p> 
                            <p><a href="#">Lots of links go here</a></p> 
                            <p><a href="#">Lots of links go here</a></p> 
                            <p><a href="#">Lots of links go here</a></p> 
                          </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>

                </div> 

            </div> 

        </div> 

    </body>

</html>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

I'm sure it's probably something quite straightforward but I can't get my head around it.

Comment: Could you explain what's wrong? Also, are you sure people are going to be using IE6?

Comment: Sorry. In IE6 when I hover over 'Delivery Info' there is no menu that appears. In all modern browsers a menu does appear underneath. Can you try the JSDOit example in a modern browser and (if possible) in IE6 too? I believe some users will still be using IE6 - I know, I know :)

Comment: @CoffeeRain I assume "what is wrong" is that nothing happens on hover. Which is as expected since IE6 does not support the `:hover` pseudo class

Comment: You can eat it, but preferrably destroy it and remove it from the history books...like it never happened :D

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Is there a workaround available to force the hover in IE6?

Comment: You could try [this](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/css-selectorhover-hack-for-ie6.html) although I have never used it. Otherwise, I would just use javascript (see @Kaido's answer)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts I used your 'csshover.htc' solution and it worked beautifully!!! Thank you. Thanks to Kaido too for the JS alternative.

Comment: Excellent, I will know to sugggest that in future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find [this](http://blog.delivi.com/javascript/hover-for-non-anchor-elements-in-ie6) an easy JQuery workaround.

HTML...

```
<div id="theBox" class="hoverable">
<h2>Hover Over Me!</h2>
</div>
```

Just add the class "hoverable" to all of the tags you want to be hovered over.

CSS...

```
#theBox {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#F1E592;
    margin:50px auto;
    border:5px solid #540505;
}
#theBox.hovered, #theBox:hover {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#540505;
    border:margin:50px auto;
    border:5px solid #F1E592;
}
```

JQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.hoverable').hover(
          function() {
             $(this).addClass('hovered'); /* On hover add the class 'hovered' and apply the hovered styles */
          }, function() {
             $(this).removeClass('hovered'); /* On mouseout remove the class 'hovered' and reset the styles   */
          }
       );
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a jquery fix here
http://www.danvega.org/blog/2008/1/1/CSS-hover-selector

We have to use a similar fix to display transparent pngs. 
(IE6 with javascript off just isn't going to look pretty any way you look at it.)

Answer (score 0):

Problem ie6 hover function doesnt work "li:hover"  which hover function work only on "a" tag

so we are using jQuery "li"  hover function , which will support all browsers

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('ul#nav li').hover(function()
              {
              $(this).find('ul').stop(true,true).slideDown()
              },
              function()
              {
              $(this).find('ul').stop(true,true).slideUp()
});
</script>
```

Please check this demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/nPdNd/29/

If you have any doubt just reply here